# how to create mongoDB connection using scala?

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am new from scala, I want to create new MongoDb connection using mongoURI or any methods.I tried some ways but did not get any good solutions.Can any one help me how to create MongoDb.

**Driver** : mongo-scala-driver_2.12-2.7.0.jar

**Sample Code ::**

```
import org.mongodb.scala.MongoClient
import org.mongodb.scala.MongoDatabase
import org.mongodb.scala._
class MongoConnection {

  def createMongoConnection() {    
    val uri: String = "mongodb://user:pass@192.168.1.10:27017/";
    val client: MongoClient = MongoClient(uri);
    val db: MongoDatabase = client.getDatabase("testdb");
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "create MongoDb". 2. Using `;` to end each line of code is not idiomatic in Scala.

Comment: i want to create new mongodb connection @cchantep

Comment: And so? What the issue?

Comment: It is totally ok to use a connection string as in your sample code. See the official example for how to put things together in a single main method: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/master/examples/src/test/scala/tour/QuickTour.scala